# Way to get back to unsaved work on Quotev.com?

Tags: quotev.com

I've been writing a story on Quotev.com using Google Chrome and a long chapter I was in the middle of writing is no longer there because my computer overheated and shut down. When I reopened Google Chrome, it asked if I want to restore my session, so I did, thinking it would bring me back. It did not save my work and, while I would just rewrite the chapter, I am very proud of this chapter and cannot seem to remember what I had written. How can I recover the missing chapter?

Comment: You have to ask Quotev Support because they most likely know how to restore it. We random folks are less likely to know how to manually restore it.

Comment: I was going to suggest using [Lazarus](http://getlazarus.com/) for future, which [seems to support contenteditable divs](http://getlazarus.com/changelog). But in my test it didn't save the body text. Probably because it's a `body`, not a `div`. You may still find Lazarus useful though.

Answer (score 3):

> I've been writing a story on Quotev.com using Google Chrome and a long chapter I was in the middle of writing is no longer there because my computer overheated and shut down.

That’s an issue you should look into. If all you were doing was writing some text in a web-browser, it should not have overheated. You should find out what happened and what process was pegging the CPU to cause to get that hot.

Also consider getting a temperature monitor like SpeedFan so that you can keep an eye on your [temperatures](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php), and if your hardware supports it, automatically adjust fan speeds to cool it down. If it’s a laptop, consider a laptop cooler.

> When I reopened Google Chrome, it asked if I want to restore my session, so I did, thinking it would bring me back. It did not save my work

What do you mean? Did it not re-open the tabs you had open at all or just not restore the text you had type in the web-page?

Chrome keeps a set of files to track your session. It keeps a list of the currently opened tabs/windows in `Current Tabs` (go figure), and a copy of the actual contents of web-forms in `Current Session`.

When Chrome crashes, it can usually (but not always) detect that it didn’t shut down correctly and offer to restore your session. In that case, it will read the files and restore your tabs and re-fill the forms.

The problem is that Quotev only uses standard HTML forms and form elements for the story meta-data (title, type, etc.), not for the story body itself. For the main body, they use, well, actually a `<body>` tag embedded in an IFrame. This is really unusual and non-standard which has the unfortunate effect that Chrome can/does not save the story at all (that HTML tag is not meant to be a text container).

Therefore, when you selected to restore your session, it probably re-opened the previous tabs and re-set the radio buttons and lists and such, and left just the main text empty (again, because Chrome has no idea that element was being used as a text container).

When I first read your question, I was going to suggest trying to manually extract text from the session files or even resort to using a disk-editor to scan the hard-drive, but unfortunately Chrome *never saved the text* in the first place, so there is *nothing* to recover).

Sadly, this means you have little recourse other than complaining to Quotev to explain the problems with their design and tell them that they should re-design it to use standard forms. (Because of the nature of the problem, it cannot even fall to Chrome to try to extend its session-saving abilities; it is incumbent only on Quotev to fix the problem)

> while I would just rewrite the chapter, I am very proud of this chapter and cannot seem to remember what I had written. How can I recover the missing chapter?

I know how you feel. It is horrible to lose a bunch of work and have to start over from scratch. Even if you do manage to re-create the work, it will never be the same and you will always wonder what you lost.

Your best bet is to always type anything longer than a paragraph or two into a text-editor like Notepad and save it to a file (regularly), then copy it to the web-site only when you are done. That way you will lose as little as possible in a crash, especially if you fix the overheating issue.

---

[image: Screenshot of underlying HTML markup of Quotev’s story-editor]

Comment: As it happens, Chrome crashed while I was typing up this very answer. I restarted Chrome and click `[Restore]` and picked up where I left off. But then, the form I was typing the answer was a standard web form, so Chrome had saved its contents.

Answer (score 0):

I literally just had a similar problem with a chapter I spent a few hours polishing, then I left my computer for a few moments and when I reopened the editor page 2 pages of my hard work were gone. So indeed I panicked a whole lot like you but I simply had to look in the 'History' section that you have access to when you pass your mouse over the three lil dots at the right corner of the page. I found the older version of my chapter: with the whole 2 missing pages in it and restored it just fine. Now I know it's been a long while since you asked for help, but just thought I'd share anyways.